# Getting following error while installing `cowsay`

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, cowsay

I tried to install `cowsay` using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install cowsay
```

I received the following error message:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Are your computer doing updates? Your computer locks the folders while doing updates.

Answer (score 1):

If another `apt-get` instance is running in another terminal, you should close it or let it complete the task before running `apt-get` in another terminal. If that's not the case, remove the lock file in `/var/lib/dpkg/` directory with

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably means another `apt-get` process crashed before completion. Just log out and log in again.